# why is thin starting multiple server processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, thin, thin-client

I'm trying to run a rails app using nginx and thin. I have configured thin to run 4 servers with different socket names. This is part of my settings

```
servers: 4
socket: /tmp/thin.myapp.sock
```

On starting thin as a service, however, at first it was creating creating two process each two two with the same name. At first I thought it is because I'm running it on a 64bits machine(I used to use 32bits). But after rebooting, now It's running 3 processes per socket name. Any idea what could be causing this? I have tried checking what I could have missed, but so far it's just driving me crazy

I'm using Ubuntu 12.02, ruby 1.9.2 on rvm and rails 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my thin gem version from 1.4.1 to 1.5.0 and it worked